# How to override jquery update preprocess page

Tags: 6, javascript, theming

The objective is to exclude certain javascript files from some sections of the website.

I exclude javascript and css files in this way in the template.php file of the theme:

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {    
  $scripts = drupal_add_js();
  //PRINT THIS ARRAY AND UNSET THE UNWANTED ARRAY
  // unset($scripts['module']['sites/default/files/js/jquery-min.js']);
  unset($scripts['module']['YOUR_PATH_TO_JS']);
  $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);    
}
```

However it seems that jquery_update preprocess is executed **after** template.php, so it overrides my changes:

```
function jquery_update_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      ...
      $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);       
}
```

The code is located in `jquery_update.module`

How would be the best approach to resolve this?

I would prefer not to hack or disable the `jquery_update.module` code if possible.

Any alternative ways to exclude javascript files that doesn't involve touching the template.php file would also fix my problem I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSAlter](https://drupal.org/project/jsalter) module for D6 should solve your problem..

Project page says

> This module will not be ported to Drupal 7, because Drupal 7 core
>   natively includes a hook_js_alter(). Note that the signature and when
>   the hook is invoked is slightly different in Drupal 7 core than it is
>   in this module.
>
> This module adds a hook_js_alter() hook that other modules can use to
>   modify the javascript that gets output to the page. The module
>   provides no end-user functionality, but other modules can use this
>   module as a dependency. Check out the JS Registry, JS Debug Helper,
>   and jQuery Form Update modules for examples.